# Having trouble with ons-list and angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, onsen-ui

I declared a very simple component called **betroomList**:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('betfriends')
    .component('betroomList', {
      templateUrl: 'src/home/betroomList.template.html',
      controller: BetroomListController,
      bindings: {
        betrooms: '<'
      }
    });

  function BetroomListController() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.betrooms = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  }
})();
```

As you can see, its controller contains a table of strings. In the template HTML, I would like to create an **ons-list** with the content of this table. Here is what contains betroomList.template.html:

```
<ons-list>
  <ons-list-item ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.betrooms">
    <h1>{{item}}</h1>
  </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

My problem is that while it works fine in Google Chome it does not it Firefox. Indeed, in Chrome it correctly displays the list with 3 rows "item1", "item2" and "item3" but in Firefox I only have a list of one element "{{item}}".
In addition, the Firefox console contains an error:

```
Error: node is undefined
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:63342/BetFriends/www/lib/angular.js:8623:13
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:63342/BetFriends/www/lib/angular.js:9330:24
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:63342/BetFriends/www/lib/angular.js:8620:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:63342/BetFriends/www/lib/angular.js:8500:30
```

It might be worth noting that if I replace respectively **ons-list** with **ul** and **ons-list-item** with **li**, everything works as expected.

Does anyone have an idea why this doesn't work?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Where is ons-list and ons-list-item defined?

Comment: They both are Onsen UI components, I don't define them myself. For instance, here is the doc for <ons-list-item>: https://onsen.io/v2/docs/js/ons-list-item.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to take it up with Onsen UI.

The only thing I can see is that they recommend using 3 classes for the item, basically to be left, centre and right:

```
<ons-list-item>
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="center">Center</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
</ons-list-item>
```

You are using a H1 tag around your {{item}}. Maybe you should try using just a div, and see what it does.

Comment: Indeed, when using these specific div's, it works (the error disappeared and the interpolation of {{item}} now works). It is odd though as in the examples they give in the doc they don't always use them. Anyway, thanks :)